# Is it okay to keep a nataraja statue at Northeast corner of the house?

Tags: shiva, idols, vastu-shastra

Some sites say not to keep nataraja statue at home, but Is it okay to keep nataraja statue at Northeast corner in home?

Comment: Yes. You can.  If you want to invite and keep Shiva as Nataraja you better be pure internally and externally as he has low tolerance for mistakes...

Comment: North East is the corner of God and it is ruled by Ishana, a form of Lord Shiva.. so where is the problem?

Comment: Can you give the links of any such sites?